# Confirmation Page and foreach statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

After user fill up the data and click "Generate Report" for the confirmation .
 Once user click the Generate Report button and it's display confirmation page. The issue is , it's only display the quantity data that insert by user. Now i want to display "Pre Price" , " Quantity " , " Item Price "
[image]

I'm tried to insert multiple variable on foreach statement so that I can view all the data insert by user. How to solve it?
[image]

```html
<html>

<body>

  <table>
    <!-- Table Header -->
    <form action="extra.php" method="post">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="icon icon-tag"></span> Item</td>
          <td><span class="icon icon-layers"></span> Surface</td>
          <td><span class="icon icon-tag"></span> Unit Price</td>
          <td><span class="icon icon-cursor-move"></span> Quantity</td>
          <td><span class="icon icon-basket"></span> Item Price</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <!-- End of Table Header -->

      <!-- Table Body -->
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Wardrobes</strong></td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group"></div>
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <script>
          function getTotal() {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0, n = document.querySelectorAll(".tr-item").length; i < n; i++) {
              var price = document.getElementById('unitprice_' + i).value;
              var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_' + i).value;
              var subtotal = price * quantity;
              document.getElementById('subtotal_' + i).value = subtotal.toFixed(2);
              total += subtotal;
            }
            document.getElementById("total").value = total.toFixed(2);
          }
          window.onload = function() {
            for (var i = 0, n = document.querySelectorAll(".tr-item").length; i < n; i++) {
              document.getElementById('quantity_' + i).onkeyup = getTotal;
            }
            getTotal();
          }
        </script>

        <tr class="tr-item">
          <td>Full height Wardrobe (Swing door)</td>
          <td>
            <script>
              function myFunction1(btn1) {
                document.getElementById("unitprice_0").value = btn1;
              }
            </script>
            <div class="btn-group surface-options-group">
              <button type="button" name="btn1" onclick="myFunction1(this.value)" value="360">Laminates</button>
              <button type="button" name="btn1" onclick="myFunction1(this.value)" value="240">Veneer</button>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>SGD$<input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice_0" value="360" size="1" readonly></td>&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="quantity[Full height Wardrobe (Swing door)]" id="quantity_0" min="0" max="10000" value="0">
            <span class="quantity-unit">ft.</span>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subtotal_0" size="5" maxlength="9" value="0" readonly/> </td>
        </tr>


        <tr id="tr-item-2" class="tr-item">
          <td>Full height Wardrobe (Normal sliding door)</td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group surface-options-group">
              <button type="button" name="btn2" onclick="myFunction2(this.value)" value="360">Laminates</button>
              <button type="button" name="btn2" onclick="myFunction2(this.value)" value="240">Veneer</button>
            </div>
            <script>
              function myFunction2(btn2) {
                document.getElementById("unitprice_1").value = btn2;
              }
            </script>
          </td>
          <td>SGD$<input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice_1" value="360" size="1" readonly></td>&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="quantity[Full height Wardrobe (Normal sliding door)]" id="quantity_1" min="0" max="10000" value="0">
            <span class="quantity-unit">ft.&nbsp;&nbsp;SGD$</span>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subtotal_1" size="5" maxlength="9" value="0.00" readonly/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tr-item">
          <td>Full height Open Wardrobe</td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group surface-options-group">
              <button type="button" name="btn3" onclick="myFunction3(this.value)" value="200">Polyken</button>
              <button type="button" name="btn3" onclick="myFunction3(this.value)" value="330">Veneer</button>
            </div>
            <script>
              function myFunction3(btn3) {
                document.getElementById("unitprice_2").value = btn3;
              }
            </script>
          </td>
          <td>SGD$<input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice_2" value="200" size="1" readonly></td>&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="quantity[Full height Open Wardrobe]" id="quantity_2" min="0" max="10000" value="0">
            <span class="quantity-unit">ft.&nbsp;&nbsp;SGD$</span>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="subtotal_2" id="subtotal_2" size="5" maxlength="9" value="0.00" readonly/> </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
  <center><button type="submit" name="btUpdate">Generate Report</button></center>
  </div>
  <div id="pricing-total">
    <h3><span class="icon icon-calculator"></span> Total Price</h3>
    <p>SGD$<input type="text" id="total" value="0" /></p>
  </div>

  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Confirmation Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        //Get the input.
        if (isset($_POST['btUpdate'])) {
            $stockData = $_POST['quantity'];
   
        }
        ?>
        <p> Confirmation.</p>
        <table width="559" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th width="407">Product</th>
                <th width="126">Per Price</th>
                <th width="126">Quantity</th>
                <th width="126">Iteam Price</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $stock_total = 0;
   
            foreach ($stockData as $key => $value) {
           
                ?>
                <?php
                $stock_total = $stock_total + $value;
                if (!empty($value)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr> 
                        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
                        <td></td>
                        
                        
                    </tr>
            <?php  }
            } ?>

            <tr>
                <td >Total Items</td>
                <td width="126"><?php print $stock_total; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you only getting the quantity? $stockData = $_POST['quantity'];

Answer (score 0):

I created arrays for all the inputs, i.e. for product, unitprice, quantity and subtotal. And onclick of the buttons, changed the unit price along with product name in the form hidden input for the product. Also recalculated subtotal and total.

```
<html>

<body>
    <form action="extra.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <!-- Table Header -->
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="icon icon-tag"></span> Item</td>
          <td><span class="icon icon-layers"></span> Surface</td>
          <td><span class="icon icon-tag"></span> Unit Price</td>
          <td><span class="icon icon-cursor-move"></span> Quantity</td>
          <td><span class="icon icon-basket"></span> Item Price</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <!-- End of Table Header -->

      <!-- Table Body -->
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Wardrobes</strong></td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group"></div>
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tr-item">
          <td>Full height Wardrobe (Swing door)</td>
          <td>
            <script>
              function myFunction1(btn1) {
                document.getElementById("unitprice_0").value = btn1;
                document.getElementById("product_0").value = "Full height Wardrobe (Swing door) - " + btn1.textContent;
                document.getElementById("unitprice_0").value = btn1.value;
              }
            </script>
            <div class="btn-group surface-options-group">
              <button type="button" name="btn1" onclick="myFunction1(this);getTotal();" value="360">Laminates</button>
              <button type="button" name="btn1" onclick="myFunction1(this);getTotal();" value="240">Veneer</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="Full height Wardrobe (Swing door) - Laminates" id="product_0" />
          </td>
          <td>SGD$<input type="text" name="unitprice[]" id="unitprice_0" value="360" size="1" readonly></td>&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_0" min="0" max="10000" value="0">
            <span class="quantity-unit">ft.</span>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="subtotal[]" id="subtotal_0" size="5" maxlength="9" value="0" readonly/> </td>
        </tr>


        <tr id="tr-item-2" class="tr-item">
          <td>Full height Wardrobe (Normal sliding door)</td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group surface-options-group">
              <button type="button" name="btn2" onclick="myFunction2(this);getTotal();" value="360">Laminates</button>
              <button type="button" name="btn2" onclick="myFunction2(this);getTotal();" value="240">Veneer</button>
            </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="Full height Wardrobe (Normal sliding door) - Laminates" id="product_1" />
            <script>
              function myFunction2(btn2) {
                document.getElementById("product_1").value = "Full height Wardrobe (Normal sliding door) - " + btn2.textContent;
                document.getElementById("unitprice_1").value = btn2.value;
              }
            </script>
          </td>
          <td>SGD$<input type="text" name="unitprice[]" id="unitprice_1" value="360" size="1" readonly></td>&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" min="0" max="10000" value="0">
            <span class="quantity-unit">ft.&nbsp;&nbsp;SGD$</span>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="subtotal[]" id="subtotal_1" size="5" maxlength="9" value="0.00" readonly/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="tr-item">
          <td>Full height Open Wardrobe</td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn-group surface-options-group">
              <button type="button" name="btn3" onclick="myFunction3(this);getTotal();" value="200">Polyken</button>
              <button type="button" name="btn3" onclick="myFunction3(this);getTotal();" value="330">Veneer</button>
            </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="Full height Open Wardrobe - Polyken" id="product_2" />
            <script>
              function myFunction3(btn3) {
                document.getElementById("product_2").value = "Full height Open Wardrobe - " + btn3.textContent;
                document.getElementById("unitprice_2").value = btn3.value;                
              }
            </script>
          </td>
          <td>SGD$<input type="text" name="unitprice[]" id="unitprice_2" value="200" size="1" readonly></td>&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_2" min="0" max="10000" value="0">
            <span class="quantity-unit">ft.&nbsp;&nbsp;SGD$</span>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" name="subtotal[]" id="subtotal_2" size="5" maxlength="9" value="0.00" readonly/> </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
  <center><button type="submit" name="btUpdate">Generate Report</button></center>
  </div>
  <div id="pricing-total">
    <h3><span class="icon icon-calculator"></span> Total Price</h3>
    <p>SGD$<input type="text" name="grandtotal"  id="total" value="0" readonly /></p>
  </div>

  </form>
<!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>-->
        <script>
          function getTotal() {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0, n = document.querySelectorAll(".tr-item").length; i < n; i++) {
              var price = document.getElementById('unitprice_' + i).value;
              var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_' + i).value;
              var subtotal = price * quantity;              
              console.log(price + "   " + quantity);
              document.getElementById('subtotal_' + i).value = subtotal.toFixed(2);
              total += subtotal;
            }
            document.getElementById("total").value = total.toFixed(2);
          }
          window.onload = function() {
            for (var i = 0, n = document.querySelectorAll(".tr-item").length; i < n; i++) {
              document.getElementById('quantity_' + i).onchange = getTotal;
            }
            getTotal();
          };
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

extra.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Confirmation Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Confirmation.</p>
        <table width="559" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th width="407">Product</th>
                <th width="126">Per Price</th>
                <th width="126">Quantity</th>
                <th width="126">Iteam Price</th>
            </tr>
                    <?php 
                    $i=0;
                    $total_items = 0;
                    foreach($_POST["product"] as $key) {
                        If($_POST["quantity"][$i]!=0) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$_POST["product"][$i]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$_POST["unitprice"][$i]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$_POST["quantity"][$i]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$_POST["subtotal"][$i]."</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        } 
                        $total_items += $_POST["quantity"][$i];

                        $i++;
                    }                  

                    ?>

            <tr>
                <td >Total Items</td>
                <td colspan="2"><?php echo $total_items; ?></td>
                <td>Total - <?php echo $_POST["grandtotal"] ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Bro. Thanks alot. The code is work now. If i just want to display the products which user input / insert quantity.                                        
Example :-  let say user insert quantity on "Full height Wardrobe (Swing door) " and " Full height Open Wardrobe " only . Than on the confirmation page just display the products which user insert and skip those product which not insert data .

Comment: Don't show, if quantity is zero. Edited the code. Do check.

Comment: Hi  T.Shah  . Thanks for the code. It's work now.  :)                             Appreciate your help  on this .                      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080867/send-the-html-table-and-contact-information-form-to-email